# About characteristic lengths

Tags: condensed-matter

I am reading about mesoscopic characteristic lengths.But I am not able to distinguish between phase coherence length $L_{phi}$ and inelastic length $L_{in}$.
please tell me the difference and especially which one is preferable in which regime. Also, which of these varies with disorder or which on not and why..?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer you what is coherence length. Consider the Mach-Zender interferometer. A single particle wave-packet is split at a beam-splitter ($BS_1$) into two wave-packets, one transmitted and one reflected. Well, each wave-packet is brought, by reflecting it with mirrors, to a second beam-splitter ($BS_2$). Say, the reflected wave-packet from $BS_1$ illuminates the upper face of $BS_2$, and the transmitted wave-packet from $BS_1$ illuminates the lower face of $BS_2$.

The two wave-packets meeting at $BS_2$ will partly leave $BS_2$ through its upper face, and partly through its lower face. Let's follow what we see as exiting the **upper face** (though we can study $Out_{lower}$ as well). Let's call this wave-packet $Out_{upper}$ If we increase the length of the path between $BS_1$ and $BS_2$, for, say, the reflected wave-packet, we will see that the intensity of $Out_{upper}$ oscillates, something as sine square, or cosine square. This happens because the reflected and the transmitted wave-packets **interfere** at $BS_2$, and the interference can be more constructive, or more destructive, depending on the path-length difference between the two packets.

But, if we increase and increase the path-length of the reflected wave-packet, at some moment the oscillations will disappear. Why? Because the reflected and transmitted wave-packets **don't meet anymore** at $BS_2$, and therefore don't interfere. When the reflected packet arrives at $BS_2**, the transmitted was there beforehand, and went away.

This is the **coherence length**: the maximal path-length difference that will still produce oscillations in the intensity of $Out_{upper}$ (or of $Out_{lower}$ if you prefer). In simple words, how long are the reflected and the transmitted packet. When the path-length difference exceeds this length, by the time that one of the wave-packets reaches $BS_2$, the other wave-packet is no more there.